# How to access a hash inside an array in Smarty

Tags: arrays, hash, smarty

just a simple question which I could not find via Google.
I have an array and one of the elements has a hash. I would like to know how to access that hash specifically the amount:

This is the array

```
[tsh_promotion_details] =>
[{"id":"1","amount":10,"type":"product.percentage","product_price":69.9,"product_quantity":1}]
```

With `{$position.attributes.tsh_promotion_details|@print_r}`
I receive this:

```
[{"id":"1","amount":10,"type":"product.percentage","product_price":69.9,"product_quantity":1}]
```

But I have no idea hot to access the amount. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it in the end.
If anyone faces a similar problem here the solution:
Basically it was a nested json inside the array.
Via Smarty's Json_decode you can transform it into an array and like usually print the thing out.

{assign var=foo value=$position.attributes.tsh_promotion_details|json_decode}